# Decide whether a set of $4$ elements is a ring given operations defined by a table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ring-theory

I am having trouble with determining whether this is a ring.
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}+&a&b&c&d\\\hline
a&a&b&c&d\\
b&b&a&d&c\\
c&c&d&a&b\\
d&d&c&b&a
\end{array}\quad\quad
\begin{array}{c|cccc}\cdot&a&b&c&d\\\hline
a&a&a&a&a\\
b&a&b&c&d\\
c&a&a&a&a\\
d&a&b&c&d
\end{array}
$$

I know that a is the additive identity, but according to the multiplication chart, shouldn't c be the additive identity as well?

Comment: I don't see why $c$ should be the additive identity. We have $b\cdot c = c$ and $d\cdot c = c$, both results are different from $a$.

Comment: I guess i assumed it to be because rows a and c were the same. I see what you mean though.

Comment: Does your definition of ring include an identity? Because there is no multiplicative identity from one side.

Comment: These were the properties my teacher mentioned when determining whether something was a ring:Commutative Law of +
Associative Law of +
Existence of an identity for +
Existence of inverses under +
Associate Law of ×
Distributive Law of × over +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $a=(0,0), b=(1,0),c=(0,1),d=(1,1)$ and define $$(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)=(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)\\(x_1,y_1)\cdot(x_2,y_2)=(x_1x_2,x_1y_2).$$ where addition and multiplication internally are in $\mathbb Z_2$.

That addition forms a group is easy.

Then $$(x_1,y_1)\cdot (x_2,y_2)\cdot(x_3,y_3)=(x_1x_2x_3,x_1x_2y_3)$$ in any order, so multiplication is associative.

Distributive law is similarly easy.

Not sure if there is a great way to prove this other than showing that your original tables correspond to the tables for this ring.

---

Generalization. Probably too advanced for an intro class, but it amused me.

In general, if $R$ is a ring, and $M$ is an $R$-module, and there is a homomorphism $\phi:M\to R$ of $R$-modules, we can define multiplication on $M$ as:

$$m_1\times m_2 = \phi(m_1)m_2.$$

Then $M$ is a ring under this and its inherited $R$-module addition. Associativity follows from:

$$\phi(\phi(m_1)m_2)=\phi(m_1)\phi(m_2)$$

Distributive law:

$$\begin{align}
m_1\times(m_2+m_3)&=\phi(m_1)(m_2+m_3)\\
&=\phi(m_1)m_2+\phi(m_1)m_3\\
&=m_1\times m_2 + m_1\times m_3
\end{align}$$
and:

$$\begin{align}
(m_1+m_2)\times m_3&=\phi(m_1+m_2)m_3\\
&=(\phi(m_1)+\phi(m_2))m_3\\
&=\phi(m_1)m_3+\phi(m_2)m_3\\
&=m_1\times m_3+m_2\times m_3
\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry, but just to clarify, doing this proves that the charts are rings correct?

Comment: Yes. The only real way to prove something is a ring is either to go through all the cases, or to find some "structure" that the ring matches, and prove the structure is a ring. Here, I suggest that the $+/\times$ tables for this new structure is the same as yours, and then prove the new structure is a ring.

Comment: One last thing, how would i prove that there are additive inverses?

Comment: Given that $a$ is the additive identity, just show that $x+x=a$ for $x=a,b,c,d$.